# SQL - join on table with duplicate keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I apologize if its confusing but..i try my best :)

**Customer Table**

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ CustomerKey    DayOfUpdate    Info1    Info2 ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1              201201         x        x     ║
║ 1              201305         x        x     ║
║ 1              201405         x        x     ║
║ 2              201306         x        x     ║
║ 3              201308         x        x     ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

**Accounts Table**

```
╔═══════════════════════════╗
║     CustomerKey    AccKey ║
╠═══════════════════════════╣
║     1              1      ║
║     2              2      ║
║     3              3      ║
╚═══════════════════════════╝
```

I want the newest information about every customer who has an AccKey value in table Accounts

I've tried to do a:

```
SELECT a.customerkey, 
       b.info1, 
       b.info2, 
       b.info3 
FROM   accounts a 
       JOIN customer b 
         ON a.customerkey = b.customerkey 
WHERE  acckey IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
```

That returns, for example, 3 rows for the customer with a `CustomerKey` of 1, but I only want the newest information about him, the row with the newest day of update. How can I write that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select a.CustomerKey, b.info1, b.info2, b.info3
  from accounts a
  join customer b
    on a.customerKey = b.CustomerKey
 where AccKey in (1, 2, 3)
   and b.dayofupdate =
       (select max(x.dayofupdate)
          from customer x
         where x.customerkey = b.customerkey)
```

Uses a sub to get the highest dayofupdate value for each customer (each customerkey)

Answer (score 2):

Below are a couple of other methods, assuming SQL Server 2005 or later:

**Solution 1 (CROSS APPLY)**

```
SELECT a.customerkey, 
       b.info1, 
       b.info2, 
       b.info3 
FROM   accounts a 
       CROSS apply (SELECT TOP (1) * 
                    FROM   customer b 
                    WHERE  a.customerkey = b.customerkey
                    ORDER BY b.dayofupdate DESC) AS b 
WHERE  acckey IN ( 1, 2, 3 );
```

**Solution 2 (CTE)**

```
WITH latest_customers 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY customerkey 
                    ORDER BY dayofupdate DESC) AS row_num 
         FROM   customer) 
SELECT a.customerkey, 
       b.info1, 
       b.info2, 
       b.info3 
FROM   accounts a 
       JOIN latest_customers b 
         ON a.customerkey = b.customerkey 
WHERE  acckey IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) 
       AND row_num = 1.
```